# MySQL Workbench workspace restoration?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I migrated to another domain so my username is different now but I did backup my C:\Users\Username when I opened MySQL Workbench 5.2.44 CE I don't see the previously saved connections and sql queries I had... How can I restore them? PS:the old Username and files are still on my computer.
OS:Win7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data is under `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench`.

Btw, I strongly recommend to update to the [latest MySQL Workbench release](http://mysqlworkbench.org).

Comment: Thanks I thought Application Data and AppData were the same .. but when I made show hidden files, I realized they are different =) will update!

Comment: Is that still accurate as of version 6.1? I somehow can't find it, but I could find them from 6.0 just a minute ago... O_o

Comment: All MySQL Workbench versions share the same data folder, so yes, the same folder is valid for even the latest WB version (6.2 at the time of this writing).

Answer (score -1):

Delete all files under C:\Users<user name>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces.

after that open mysql installer and click on reconfigure mysql server and click on next till end

Now open mysql workbench it will work.

Comment: Hi @Naitik Raval, I think the issue here is not so much the getting mysql workbench running, but rather trying to restore all the settings and queries that the original poster had previously saved.  From that perspective, I believe deleting the old workspaces seems like it might eliminate the possibility of restoring that data.